# Ota update and factory reset after rooting

Tags: rooting, unrooting

In Galaxy note4 910k ,After rooting ,
I did *unrooting using Magisk or super SU to prevent the bank app and rooting check app from detecting rooting.
but if I do the factory reset or OTA update in this situation, will the bank app stop working?

I saw many cases that after reset, root checking apps cant detect root, but banking apps dont run